# wrapfig: frame around image and caption

Tags: graphics, captions, framed

I have an image wich is beside some text, and I would want to frame the image and the caption.

My code is for now:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{8cm}
    \centering
     \fbox{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{Encodages}}
    \caption[Différents encodages]{Différents types d'encodage pour «Wikipédia, l'encyclopédie libre»}
\end{wrapfigure}
BLABLABLA TEXT
```

but the fbox is only around the image. How could I do that?

Comment: what happens if you move the `\caption{}` inside the `\fbox{}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{8cm}
 \fbox{%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr8cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}\centering
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{Encodages}
    \caption[Différents encodages]{Différents types d'encodage pour «Wikipédia, l'encyclopédie libre»}
   \end{minipage}}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here is a solution with the `framed` package:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{heuristica}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig, framed, caption}
    \usepackage{lipsum}%

    %\captionsetup{ width = 2cm}%singlelinecheck = false,

    \begin{document}

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{\dimexpr 6cm + 2\FrameSep + 2\FrameRule\relax}%
    \begin{framed}\raggedleft%\centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{0sendak}%
    \caption{Where the Wild Things Are,  by \emph{Maurice Sendak}}
    \end{framed}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the distance between the frame borders and the image is too big, you can remove space adding `vspace{-0.5cm}` right after `\begin{framed}` and before `\end{framed}`