# Box around figures and caption in floated figures with subfigures

Tags: captions, wrapfig, frame

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text only

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[15]{l}{6.5cm}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} &% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{orange}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} \\% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{green}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} &% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{yellow}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} \\% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} &% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{brown}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} \\% Dummy image replacement
    \end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

How do I create a label to place on each figure, a caption under the entire figure and also wrap all the figures and the caption in a box so it is separated from the main text that it is floated around?

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What do you mean by "a label to place on each figure" - is that text that goes at the center of each colored square, or text underneath (like a subcaption)? For a caption of the whole figure, use `\caption{This will be underneath}` just before `\end{wrapfigure}`. To frame the figure, take a look at this question: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/frame-around-image-and-caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/frame-around-image-and-caption)

Comment: I had already tried the solutions in the link above using 'framed' and 'mdframed' packages but it did not work for my specific use case in which I am including multiple figures using a tabular environment.

Comment: By “label” I mean text that you place on a figure (preferably in a corner of the image) to identify it as part A, part B etc.

Comment: If it's in a table then you can add the descriptions of each figure in a table row underneath the figure. Or do you actually want a text on top of the figures?

Comment: I would prefer that the label be in the figure, but can you provide an example code of what you had in mind? Also, I am still having trouble with enclosing all the figures and the caption I want to place underneath the entire figure inside a box or frame, so help with that would be welcome as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment: enclose with `\begin{framed}` and `\end{framed}` from the package `framed`, a `\caption` for the tabular, and extra tabular rows with image descriptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text only
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begingroup
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[30]{l}{7cm}
\begin{framed}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} &% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{orange}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} \\% Dummy image replacement
    part A & part B\\ 
    \textcolor{green}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} &% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{yellow}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} \\% Dummy image replacement
    part C & part D\\
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} &% Dummy image replacement
    \textcolor{brown}{\rule{3cm}{3cm}} \\% Dummy image replacement
    part E & part F\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{general caption}
\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]