# Framing a figure with its caption

Tags: graphics, frame

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering\text{Títle}\par\medskip
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=5.5cm,height=5cm]{img/Distribucióncentros.png}}
\caption{Example picture.}  \vspace*{-5mm} Source: \cite{HITOSHI22022020}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

I have the following code and I want to frame the figure, that the frame is adjusted to the figure and that it includes the title and the caption as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [frame around image and caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/frame-around-image-and-caption)

Comment: @NBur Your suggested answer only deals with the `wrapfigure`  environment, not the `figure` environment. These work in different ways.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425122

Comment: @PeterWilson I modified the title so that this confusion will not happen again.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can do.

```
% boxfigprob.tex  SE 593681

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{6.75cm}
\begin{framed}
\centering
TITLE \par\medskip
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-duck}
\caption{A racing duck}
\end{framed}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like the interest of the OP has vanished :). +1 from me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Adding border around figure and caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425122)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425122
\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}
  \lineskip=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{The caption text}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]